# не доходит POST запрос через AJAX (чистый js)

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, post

JS код

```
var bodypost = 'name=' + params['name'] + '&test=' +murmur; // params['name'] и murmur рабочие переменные
let xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
xhttp.open("POST","http://strmine.ru/fp.php", true);
xhttp.setRequestHeader('Content-Type','application/x-www-form-urlcoded');
xhttp.send(bodypost);
```

PHP код

````
$fp = $_POST["test"];
$name = $_POST["name"];
    $mysqli = new mysqli ("localhost", "???", "???", "???");
    $mysqli ->query ("SET NAMES 'utf8'");
    $success = $mysqli ->query ("UPDATE detector2 SET fphash='".$fp."' WHERE user ='".$name."' ");
    $mysqli ->close ();```
Все это на 1 домене, на локалхосте
````

Comment: А что с себя представляет bodypost ? и js лежит на этом (strmine.ru) домене, на который идет запрос) ? или js на одном, а запрос на другой ? + к всему в Chrome DevTools (вкладке network) можно почти все клиентские запросы на сервер

Comment: у тебя бэкенд не посылает ничего в ответ

Comment: У меня цель этого всего тупо для того чтобы вытащить из JS нудное мне значение и уже через php его обработать, мне ответ на js не нужен

Comment: @nörbörnën а бекенд должен обязательно отправлять ответ?

Answer (score 0):

Используйте [formdata](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/API/FormData)

```
let xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
let body = new FormData();
body.append('someParameter', 'someValue');
body.append('someParameter1', 'someValue1');
body.append('someParameter2', 'someValue2');
xhttp.open("POST","http://strmine.ru/fp.php", true);
xhttp.send(body);
```

Answer (score 0):

Возможно ошибка в отправляемом заголовке.

У вас `urlcoded`, а нужно `urlencoded`.

```
xhr.setRequestHeader('Content-Type', 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded');
```